# Array Pointer thread safety

Tags: c#, arrays, thread-safety

Let's assume we have an array in C# which is accessed from mutliple threads, is it thread safe to change this array in runtime? (not as in to change its data, but to change the pointer). In other words, is writing an Array pointer an atomic operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing the address of a new pointer is an atomic operation:

> **5.5 Atomicity of variable references**
>
> Reads and writes of the following data types are atomic: bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, and reference types. In addition, reads and writes of enum types with an underlying type in the previous list are also atomic. Reads and writes of other types, including long, ulong, double, and decimal, as well as user-defined types, are not guaranteed to be atomic.

Since an array pointer is a reference, it is thread safe.

In order to avoid *cache side-effects*, you can use the `volatile` keyword as well.

---

However you must be very carefull with this. Say you have a method:

```
public class Foo {

    private volatile int[] data;

    public void Method () {
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public void OtherMethod (int[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Say you set the `data` array to an array with a different length, it is possible that the `for`-loop checks the length fetches the length of the old array, then the reference is modified to a shorter array and then you access an illegal index.

Non-blocking multithreaded applications, therefore make a copy of the *reference* to the array, modify the array and then check if the *reference* is modified.

Comment: Thank you so much! (can't accept it yet, but I will when it becomes available)

Comment: However you need to be carefull. Say you have a method that first makes a copy of the *reference to the array*, the copy will of course not be modified.

Comment: Furthermore I've added an example to show that you still must be very careful with this thread safe operations.

Comment: Ah yeah I got that, I can live with that. I just wanted it proven somewhere that it's valid :)